# Help creating a script which can play to audio files consecutively no matter the length

Tags: php, javascript, audio, call

I am working on a call board for the hospital I work for. The call board will be used for announcing CODES, FIRE, and a few other types of calls. My problem is that I am trying to play two WAV files consecutively the first file is the type of call and the second file is the location. We have over 700 possible locations and I do not want to have thousands of pre-made recordings. Please help. Also I have thought about using a speech speech synthesizer like Microsoft ANNA.

Comment: This does not sound like a job for PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the audio clips as MP3s. Concatenating them is simple - simply output one after the other. MP3s have no internal structure beyond a "frame". An MP3 file is simply a series of these frames, which can be mixed in with other data (ie: mpeg video).

```
<?php

header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');

readfile('good.mp3');
readfile('morning.mp3');
readfile('zombie attack.mp3');
readfile('imminent.mp3');
readfile('arm yourself.mp3');
```

Of course, doing this sort of thing via a web inteface seems silly. How would you tell the PA system to poke at the server to play something?

Comment: The Operator would select Code and the room number from the browser which would in turn make the server play the 2 audio files. The Server outputs sound to a analog input on the PA System. The goal here is to save money by creating a customizable call system instead of purchasing expensive equipment.

Comment: Ah. gotcha. Well, then the script snippet I posted should get you started. You'd have to embed it the output into an mp3 player (flash, html5, etc...) but the script will generate the audio file output for you.